# Azure random 404 on valid URL in Application Insights

Tags: angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, azure-application-insights

My website uses AngularJS (v1) with webapi. I have a file upload directive that posts to my file upload controller. On some calls to the file upload, I get a 404 not found on a valid address. Most of the time it works as expected. If I look through the Application Insights on Azure, I can see some weird reporting in regards to the file upload api. See images

[image: First image with 404]
[image: Second image no 404]

In the first image in the left column, I can see 8 errors reported with a POST to /api/fileupload/upload. Middle column shows all 8 are 404s, and in the third column, I can see the request URL, which if I copy and paste into the browser, doesn't return a 404 (returns a 405, method not allowed which I'd expect as it doesn't support GET requests but it **does** find the url).

The second image shows a valid api request (this error is expected). The left column shows a POST to fileupload/upload (**NOT** /api/fileupload/upload/ as in the first image that 404s), but the middle and left columns show the same request URL as the 404 in the first image.

In angular, I only call the API from one spot in my file upload directive:

```
angular.element($element).fileupload({
    url: 'api/fileupload/upload/',
    type: 'POST',
    ...
    ...
});
```

What are these 404s? How can I stop them? How can I find out where its going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding calls to upload resulting in 404: it is a known issue that ASP.NET can return 404s when attempting to upload files that exceed allowed size. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12843209/788382) for more details.
Regarding the error on your second image, it is unclear from your question, whether  these are expected, or not, but to note - this is 400, not 404 and 400s can be thrown for invalid routing.

Comment: The 400 is expected behavior, I return a 400 if a bad file type is detected (such as exe). I am meaning that in the second screenshot the URL is found (not 404'ing). I will test this and see if I can reproduce the behaviour. Thanks.